# couple questions for a server

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have a theoretical question I'm hoping you can help me with.

Alright I have a home based server
300 down/30 up Internet (the best I can get where I am at).
I have a static IP and Permission from my IP to host my said server.

Alright everything's in place right? No, well maybe.

Being my server isn't top of the line I worry about 1 single thing,
let's say when I release my App (using my server as a back-end).

Let's say I have 20 thousand active users daily for 1 hour each per day, what's the likelihood of hundreds of people submitting posts (think of twitter posting, only text though) at one given time between 0-300 milliseconds.

What I mean is, think of MySQL, running queries, would 500 people posting text of 140 characters each drop a system to a crawl even with (in a perfect world - perfectly designed queries). And what would the likelihood be that 500 people submit at the same 0-300ms.. To me it doesn't seem very likely until you get into hundreds of thousands of people.

In other words, theory of time.
20K Active users Daily.
Likelihood of estimated theoretical queries per second IF they are all active at one given time. Lets say the average time per people posting ranges from 5-90 seconds. (Reading > Then posting).

I just don't see an issue, but something in the back of my head is making me over think this. The reason this came up is because my Web Hoster (Host-Gator) I found out had like 25 max connections to MySQL. Which freaked me out, and made me realize - what's the likelihood of 25 people at any given time on a small (20K active users on an app) reading that limit.

I haven't yet set any max connections on my server yet, I will eventually. (For obvious reasons). I just want to make sure I set it up to be optimally proficient, and in doing so, I need to at least articulate how many queries per second I can expect on average per so many people, E.G. 20K people.

To me 20K users isn't that many, but at the same time, I'm not very good at averaging things out in this kind of situation, because it's nothing but a big ('Unknown'), I mean how can I truly predict something like this without being in a live production environment. But being in a live production environment and having it smack be right back in the face and ruining my credibility to the end user is the worst that can happen.

Server Specs: (TO BE UPGRADED WHEN NEEDED).
Windows 10
8 Gigs of Ram.
Intel Core I3
Apache + PHP + MySQL (Not Xampp or Wamp), just each individual things set up.
1 TB SSD
Nothing else running on it - dedicated only for this sole purpose.

Yes I know, not very strong, but it's all I have and can afford at the moment.
There's no way in the world you'll catch me spending $174 a month for a decent dedicated server when i can save up a few months and just outright buy a new one later.

So this is just a temporary solution until I can afford something better.

Thanks guys/gals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, I would drop the Windows 10 OS and go with Ubuntu 16.
Be realistic when buying a server, as some companies advertise servers in the low hundreds, and after you really get things built out *correctly*, you are in the thousands of dollars.
Think of it like you are getting a 'chassis only'.

Second, don't try to emulate what good IP companies do for pennies on the dollar - you'll go broke and not have enough time to focus on your core application.

Once it takes off and starts generating revenue, then put your first dollars into infrastructure improvements.

Take if from someone who has gone done this path before ;)
Good luck !

Comment: That's actually a really good plan, I hate to overthink things - it just happens. I mean what's the likelihood of 20K users instantly anyways? Very slim hahaah, so chances are it will be one of them things (if it picks off) something I can upgrade over time.

Comment: Even though not a direct answer to the question, I think I should accept it as the answer because it does make a lot of sense.